# BeautifulSoup web spider for driver links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following spider will grab some driver links, OS version, and the name.
All the info is in a table class, but some pages might be a little different in the location and Number of cells in each row.

I can't post the HTML page, but the main problem I'm facing now is that sometimes the number of the row I need is in cell 0 or 1. I know it should be simple to make the spider check but I just can't think of a way to make it into the current spider.

```
import bs4


def bkc_spider(path, start, stop):
    """BKC Spider - grabs driver names, links and OS version from BKC releases"""
    ver_lst = ['Win7', 'Win8.1', 'Win10', 'WinT', 'WinN']
    file = open(path, 'rb')
    drivers = {}
    rng_lst = [str(x) for x in range(start, stop)]

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file)

    table = soup.findAll('table')[0]
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        if len(cells) > 4:
            cell_num = cells[1].get_text(strip=True)
            if any(cell_num == n for n in rng_lst):
                drv_name = cells[2].get_text(strip=True)
                drivers[drv_name] = {'links': []}
                for pTag in cells[4].findAll('p'):
                    try:
                        link = pTag.findNext('a')
                        link_os = pTag.find('span', {'class': 'MsoHyperlink'}).span.get_text(strip=True)
                        if any(link_os == ver for ver in ver_lst):
                            drivers[drv_name]['links'].append(link['href'] + " | " + link_os)
                        else:
                            drivers[drv_name]['links'].append(link['href'])
                        continue
                    except AttributeError:
                        drivers[drv_name]['links'].append(link['href'])
                        continue
    for x in drivers:
        print(x)
        for y in drivers[x]:
            print(drivers[x][y])
        print('\n')
    return drivers


html_file = r"BKC.htm"
bkc_spider(html_file, 6, 31)
```

Comment: One recommendation - 

`linkList = [];`
`drivers[drv_name] = {'links': linkList}`

And then refer to linkList instead.